# Catch error in tcl

Tags: tcl, expect

I have part of expect script, which is connecting to remote server, and running  command `/opt/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/moshell/test.xml -val:rall`. So basicily it is doing ok, but what I need is catch some errors which may happen after this command `-vall-rall` and then exit.
Here is the log of the script when is runned:

```
janko496@rtwauas1o> perl ex 

 *************************************************************
 *                     /// START ///                         *
 *************************************************************

spawn ssh mashost


Password:
Your password will expire in 15 days.

Last login: Mon Jan 26 09:51:52 2015 from rtwauas1o
janko496@rtwaadmin1o> cd /home/janko496/moshell
janko496@rtwaadmin1o> /opt/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/test.xml -val:rall
Logging to file /var/opt/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2015-01-26_09:54:12
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MUG does not support the delete upgradation operation.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Validating XML File.....
Delete XML files are only validated for DTD and limited semantic errors.....

Finished validating file /home/janko496/test.xml
There were 0 errors reported during validation

janko496@rtwaadmin1o> /opt/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/test.xml -import
Logging to file /var/opt/arne/ARNE_Import_Log.2015-01-26_09:54:23
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MUG does not support the delete upgradation operation.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting Import..
Progress :7%:Validating against mandatory rules for 'siu064842'
Progress :15%:Adjusting with NEC for 'siu064842'.
Progress :23%:Deleted Target  Information.
Progress :30%:Deleting Object 'SubNetwork=NL1,SubNetwork=EHWOUR_SIU,ManagedElement=siu064842'.
Progress :38%:Action Committed
Progress :46%:Object fully deleted.
Progress :53%:Adjusting with NEC for 'siu064842'.
Progress :61%:Transaction committed, updating Area.
Progress :100%:Temporary Area Deleted.
Import Finished.
No Errors Reported.
```

and here is the script:

```
set strname There were 0 errors reported during validation 
spawn ssh mashost
#exp_internal 1
expect {
    "assword"  {send "$PASSWORD\r"}
}
        set timeout 100
        expect "janko496@rtwaadmin1o"
        send -- "cd /home/janko496/moshell\r"
        expect "janko496@rtwaadmin1o"
        send -- "/opt/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/moshell/test.xml -val:rall \r"
        if { [string compare expect_out(0,string) strname ]  != 1 } {
        send "exit\r";
        }
        send -- "/opt/ericsson/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/test.xml -import \r"
        expect "janko496@rtwaadmin1o"
```

so I want to catch this string `"There were 0 errors reported during validation` and continue or exit if there are some error's.

Comment: There are some additional problems with your script which would prevent it from functioning. For instance, the `set` command takes one or two arguments: you should use double quotes or braces in the first line to collect the words of the value into one argument. The invocation of `string compare` takes the literal strings `expect_out(0,string)` and `strname` as arguments. Presumably you want the contents of the variables with those names instead: `$expect_out(0,string)` and `$strname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `expect` that waits for two different things at once after the:

```
send -- "/opt/arne/bin/import.sh -f /home/janko496/moshell/test.xml -val:rall \r"
```

The two things that you are waiting for are for a pattern that indicates success and a pattern that indicates failure. Note that using a regular expression pattern (`-re`) can help a lot with this, and regular expressions should (normally) be put in braces:

```
expect {
    "There were 0 errors reported during validation" {
        puts "Yay, validation succeeded"
        # You don't really need to put very much in here...
    }
    -re {There were (\d+) errors reported during validation} {
        puts "Found $expect_out(1,string) errors in validation"
        send "exit\r"
        after 100
        close
        exit
    }
}
```